# Derivation of inner product of general photon polarisation states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, quantum-electrodynamics, polarization

This relates to page 109 of [Timo Weigand's QFT notes](http://www.physics.umd.edu/grt/taj/624b/WeigandQFT.pdf). We are just imposing the Gupta-Bleuler condition on the Fock space in order to consistently quantise the electromagnetic field.

We define a general polarization vector:

$$\zeta^\mu:=\sum_{\lambda\lambda'}\alpha_\lambda \eta_{\lambda\lambda'} \epsilon^\mu(\vec p,\lambda) \tag{4.52},$$

and from there we define the corresponding photon with this polarization and momentum $\vec p$ to be

$$|\vec p,\zeta \rangle:=\sqrt{2|\vec p|}\sum_\lambda \alpha_\lambda \alpha_\lambda^\dagger(\vec p)|0\rangle \tag{4.53}.$$

This is fine, these are both just definitions, however we then go on to calculate the inner product of two such states, $|\vec p,\zeta\rangle$ and $|\vec q,\zeta'\rangle$:

$$\langle \vec q,\zeta|\vec p,\zeta'\rangle=-(2\pi)^3\cdot 2|\vec p| \delta^{(3)}(\vec p-\vec q)\zeta\cdot \zeta' \tag{4.54}.$$

If we simply expand this out we find:

$$\langle \vec q,\zeta|\vec p,\zeta'\rangle=2\sqrt{|\vec p||\vec q|}\sum_{\lambda\lambda'}\alpha_\lambda \alpha_{\lambda'}\langle0|a_\lambda(\vec q)a_{\lambda'}^\dagger(\vec p)|0\rangle,$$

then, using the commutation relation $[a_\lambda(\vec p),a_\lambda^\dagger(\vec q)]=-\eta_{\lambda\lambda'}(2\pi)^3\delta^{(3)}(\vec p-\vec q)$, we find

$$\langle \vec q,\zeta|\vec p,\zeta'\rangle=-2\cdot(2\pi)^3\sqrt{|\vec p||\vec q|}\delta^{(3)}(\vec p-\vec q)\sum_{\lambda\lambda'}\alpha_\lambda \alpha_{\lambda'}\eta_{\lambda\lambda'}.$$

Now, given that the solution given in the notes is:

$$\langle \vec q,\zeta|\vec p,\zeta'\rangle=-(2\pi)^3\cdot 2|\vec p|\delta^{(3)}(\vec p-\vec q)\zeta\cdot\zeta',\tag{4.54}$$

I must conclude that at some point the $\sqrt{|\vec q|}$ must become $\sqrt{|\vec p|}$, and somehow we need to have

$$\zeta\cdot\zeta'=\sum_{\lambda\lambda'}\alpha_\lambda \alpha_{\lambda'}\eta_{\lambda\lambda'}.$$

So, I tried to solve the latter:

$$\zeta\cdot\zeta'=\sum_{\lambda\lambda'}\sum_{\sigma\sigma'}\alpha_\lambda\alpha_\sigma\eta_{\lambda\lambda'}\eta_{\sigma\sigma'}\epsilon^{\mu}(\vec p,\lambda)\epsilon_{\mu}(\vec q,\sigma).$$

However, I encounter the problem that $\epsilon(\vec p,\lambda)\cdot \epsilon(\vec p,\lambda')=\eta_{\lambda\lambda'}$ is only valid if the momentums of the two polarization bases agree, which in this case they presumable won't because the momentum $\vec p$ and $\vec q$ of our states differs.

So I am pretty much at a loss of how to continue here, anyone able to kindly provide some guidance?

Comment: In front of the $\zeta\cdot\zeta'$ you have a $\delta^{(3)}(\vec p -\vec q)$ which enforces $\vec p = \vec q$ in your calculation of the dot product. This is why the polarisation basis agree

Comment: If we had an integral over $\vec p$ or $\vec q$ I'd agree, but the change from $\vec q$ to $\vec p$ appears to have been done with the delta function still there, so surely we are not using this? If you're telling me they've assumed the presence of an integral I'll be upset because that is very strange to just assume without acknowledging

Comment: No need for an integral. The 1D version of my claim is $f(x)\delta(x)=f(0)\delta(x)$, have you seen it?

Comment: I can't say I've seen that before, but I suppose it makes sense, if we're acknowledging that anything involving delta functions really only makes sense in the presence of an integral then $f(0)=\int f(x)\delta(x)=\int f(0)\delta(x)=f(0)\int \delta(x)=f(0)\cdot 1$. Presumably this is the argument we're making here?

Comment: Yes exactly. Actually, to make your proof rigorous, you’ll need to apply the distributions on test functions $\phi$. You get (assuming $f$ is smooth): $$\langle f\delta,\phi\rangle= \langle \delta,f\phi\rangle= f(0)\phi(0)=f(0) \langle \delta,\phi\rangle= \langle f(0)\delta,\phi\rangle$$ This generalizes to higher dimensions